# how can i send Full name in TCP service in 2nd time?

Tags: c#, sockets, networking, tcp, buffer

**When i send data through TCP server to client first time full name retrieved when i again send the another name like book it retrieved  as (ook) in C sharp**

***client side code***

sck = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            while (true)
            {

```
            IPEndPoint localEndPoint;
            localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.2"), 1);

            try
            {
                sck.Connect(localEndPoint);

            }
            catch
            {
                Console.Write("Unable to connect to remote end point!\r\n");
             );
            }
            Console.Write("Enter Text: ");
            string text = Console.ReadLine();
            byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(text);
            sck.Send(data);
            Console.Write("Data Sent!\r\n");
            sck.Close();
            Console.ReadLine();
```

---

**Server Side Code**

while (true)
                {
                    Socket accepted = sck.Accept();

```
                Buffer = new byte[accepted.SendBufferSize];
                int bytesRead = accepted.Receive(Buffer);

                byte[] formatted = new byte[bytesRead];


                for (int i = 0; i < bytesRead; i++)
                {
                    formatted[i] = Buffer[i];
                    //Console.WriteLine(Buffer[i] + "\r\n");
                }
                //string strData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(Buffer);
                string strData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(formatted);

                Console.Write(strData + "\r\n");
                accepted.Close();
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is something which I don't understand, you use Buffer as a variable but that is a type in C#, I don't know where and how you declare it. 
Anyway, I would do it like this:

```
    while (true)
    {
        Socket accepted = sck.Accept();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int ret=0;
        StringBuilder sb= new StringBuilder();
        while ((ret=accepted.Receive(buffer)) > 0)
        {
            sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, ret));
        }
        Console.Write(sb.ToString() + "\r\n");
        accepted.Close();
    }
```

In order to keep a dialog between both sockets you need something called a protocol, which means you know when you have received the whole data then you reply to the sender. A protocol could be: send a packet which inform what you are going to send, length of the message mainly. Other way is to stop reading when something comes into the message, for example the string "#END#" the return character '\r', etc. If you only want to send one single message and received back a reply message one thing you can do, however, is to shutdown the client part, only the send part `Socket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Send);`, with that, the sender tells the receiver it has sent all data, the receiver receives that signal and then it can send a reply message to the sender.

The client:

```
    sck.Send(data);
    Console.Write("Data Sent!\r\n");
    // tell the server we have done sending data.
    sck.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Send);
    // Now receive from the server
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int ret = 0;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    while ((ret = sck.Receive(buffer)) > 0)
    {
        sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, ret));
    }
    Console.Write(sb.ToString() + "\r\n");
    sck.Close();
```

The server

```
    while (true)
    {
        Socket accepted = sck.Accept();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int ret=0;
        StringBuilder sb= new StringBuilder();
        while ((ret=accepted.Receive(buffer)) > 0)
        {
            sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, ret));
        }
        Console.Write(sb.ToString() + "\r\n");
        byte[] reply = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("I've got it!");
        accepted.Send(reply);
        accepted.Close();
    }
```

Comment: I make Buffer as property thank you ja_mesa for answer  i have another question ..this program i make for client send and server receive how can i do for server reply to client. Server send the any text and client receive   can you help me

Comment: i want whenever client can send data and also server .. here is when client send any text and server receive then server send data to client but i want like chat when server want to send data it can .

Comment: Open a new question o search for similar questions in this site. Socket dialogs, socket chat, etc, sure there are a lot of them already asked and answered. I'm glad it worked for you, and you're very welcome.